# How to get information of Heroku application during provisioning?

Tags: heroku

I developed a WCF Rest service to post as add-on on Heroku. I haven't finished all steps to appear on the Heroku add-on catalog yet, I tested this add-on using `kensa`.

I would like to get information of application which are going to use my add-on using following api as per heroku document

Action : GET api.heroku.com/vendor/apps/app_id

My question is: where do I need to put and how can I test it with kensa and how it will work practically when my add-on is on Heroku?

Let's take an example , following is my Post Methods of Rest Service(C#.NET) and it would call
when i test it with "Kensa test provison" command in ruby command propmt

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",

        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "heroku/resources")]
    User PostData(User objUser);

  public User PostData(User objUser)
    {
            User usr = new User();
            usr.id = 100;
            config config = new config();
            config.MYADDON_URL = "http://localhost";
            usr.config = config;
            usr.message = "Post Data..";
            return usr;            
    }
```

How can i get appid/providerid without interacting with application ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then only information you can get from Heroku about your users is the name of the application and the owner email. There's a very important paragraph in the TOS you need to read about using users' emails.

That said, if you need to get information about an Heroku user you need to send a GET request to

```
https://api.heroku.com/vendor/apps/:provider_id
```

where `:provider_id` is the id you returned when you [provisioned the user](https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/technical/build/provisioning).

For example, if the call

```
POST /heroku/resources
```

returns

```
json { "id": 456, "message": "your message here" }
```

then you can get user details by calling

```
GET https://api.heroku.com/vendor/apps/456
```

The [API reference](https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/technical/reference/api-spec) contains the list of all available API parameters and calls.

Comment: can you please check my question again i have edited that with example , how can i get provider id in my add-on when i am testing with kensa?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is `C#` code. I don't have any `C#` knowledge. Also, I don't really understand what you are supposed to do with that code and your application. Are you sure do you need to offer a new add-on? Do you have a product or service to offer? It seems to me you are trying to develop an add-on without a product to intgrate.

Comment: Yes you are true and want to offer service through add-on but i would like to test it first and not done any actual implementation yet , i want to convey you that i am testing my service using kensa then how i can retrieve providerid?

Comment: But do you have a product? Does it exists online? Do you have users and accounts? If you don't have a product, there's nothing you can test.

Comment: my clients want to redirect to their existing application with autologin! i am dam confused how this things going to be practically even i am new about heroku and no knowledge about ruby , can you give any link who has developed add-on in .net ?

Comment: The add-on is language agnostic. The add-on itself is your product. You need to make sure your application responds to Heroku calls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3436/discussion-between-arun-rana-and-simone-carletti)

Comment: I am getting heroku id like : {<root type="object">
  <heroku_id type="string">app2433@kensa.heroku.com</heroku_id>
  <plan type="string">test</plan>
  <callback_url type="string">http://localhost:7779/callback/999</callback_url>
</root>} in opertaioncontext.requestmessage object when i am testing it with kensa so what will be my herokuid : 2433 or app2433@kensa.heroku.com? it will change at every time when i do "kensa test provision" can u please comment on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve provider_id while testing locally, therefore API calls to retrieve information about application or owner won't work, until you push your manifest to Heroku and start the alpha stage.